Movie about three adventurous friends in a place with conflict
I have a vague recollection of a movie I saw on television around a decade ago, and I would like it identified. I know that I don't have much to start with, but it's worth a shot. Here is what I remember:
Setting

The movie is in English, but probably not American.
It takes place at a rural town somewhere in the British Isles during a local political conflict
The major characters are


The main character, a young male
His father, or possibly an uncle. Lives together with the main character
His girlfriend, which he meets during the events of the movie. I think they start out as friends but their relationship develops quickly
His best friend, an adventurous guy with long hair. His nickname was Coco or possibly Koko


Story

 A good part of the movie is basically the three friends hanging out and being adventurous, the main character, his girlfriend, and his best friend. The main character gets into trouble, possibly because of his romance with the mentioned girl. He gets tarred and feathered in one scene. The girl becomes pregnant, but later has a miscarriage. The best friend dies in an accident by sinking in mud after a tractor falls on him; this happens in the presence of the main character who tries to save him.


The Run of the Country from 1995 with Albert Finney as the dad.

In a small village on the border of Northern Ireland and The Republic of Ireland, the relationship between a short tempered policeman and his rebellious son becomes even more strenuous when the young man falls for a "wrong" girl.

The son's girlfriend has a miscarriage, he's tarred and feathered in one brutal scene for seeing her and his free-spirited friend Cocoa is killed after a tractor runs him over in the mud. Based on a novel by Shane Connaughton. Here's the trailer:




This is indeed the movie I was looking for. Thanks for also mentioning the novel
